# How to test ActionProvider.onCreateActionView using Robolectric, RoboGuice, ABS?

Tags: android, robolectric

I have a ActionProvider and I want to test the onCreateActionView method. When I call this method from my test I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: LayoutInflater not found.
at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:214)
at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:16803)
at com.my.app.actionprovider.ContentTypeActionProvider.onCreateActionView(ContentTypeActionProvider.java:58)
```

Here is the method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateActionView() {


    view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.layout_actionbarpopupmenu, null);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);

    menu = new PopupMenu(context, view);


    int order = 1;

    if(ESA){
        SubMenu submenu = null;
        for (ContentType contentType : ContentType.values()) {
            if (contentType.isFirstInGroup()) {
                submenu = menu.getMenu().addSubMenu(-1, -1, order++, contentType.getGroupName());
                submenu.setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.down_arrow));
                submenu.add(contentType.getGroupId(), contentType.getId(), order++, contentType.getName());
            } else if (contentType.isGroup()) {
                submenu.add(contentType.getGroupId(), contentType.getId(), order++, contentType.getName());
            } else {
                menu.getMenu().add(contentType.getGroupId(), contentType.getId(), order++, contentType.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    else{        
        for (ContentType contentType : contentTypeHelper.getContentTypes()) {
            menu.getMenu().add(contentType.getGroupId(), contentType.getId(), order++, contentType.getName());
        }
    }

    UIHelper.setIconVisibleOnMenu(menu);
    menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            menu.show();
        }
    });

    setDefaultOption();

    return view;
}
```

Is there a way I can test this method?

Comment: Can you share your test source. Do you use `RobolectricTestRunner`?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because the context that you are using is not a correct one, to make that works you could use:

```
RuntimeEnvironment.context
```

as a mocked context if you are using Robolectric for your tests.